# Where to get started programming iBeacon BLE sensor modules?

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, sensors, beacon

I'd really love to learn to program cheap sensors and modules such as this one:
[barometer sensor nRF51822 bluetooth module ibeacon LPS22HB, CR2032 battery holder](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32955255127.html), specifically to use within iOS and Swift.

I reached out to the company who makes them and tried researching how to get started multiple times, but I really can't figure out where to start. There are also pre-programmed modules, but my interest is programming these cheap ones to fit my needs.

I have the linked module, and a few others, and they appear and can be connected to using beacon detector apps, but display no understandable info.

I'd like to read the barometer pressure reading to start. Help is highly appreciated, I'd love to start working with these.

**EDIT/UPDATE:** I was able to read the modules manufacture name on one of many iBeacon scanner apps I tried and their name is `Yunjia`. With this information I am able to find alot more details online about what I have. One website says for these chips I can use LightBlue (the app I used to find the manufacturer name) to modify, read, and write to the module. Any additional advice is welcomed, I'll be researching and testing things out.

I also found the [Schematics](http://www.holyiot.com/tp/2019042815352698708.pdf) along with some additional info hidden in the seller website.

**Edit 2:** I found the manufactures little YouTube channel with some info, looks like I just have to do lots of research and testing and learn everything. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvqhWNqDE-v0je0X8XAEF2Q  It contains some video instructions.

**Edit 3:** My short term goal of reading the barometer data was a success! After tons of digging I found I just had to write a value of `0x01` to turn on all sensors, then I was flooded with data and the barometer pressure in bytes which could be translated to the actual amount. Write `0x00` to trun off all sensors.

Comment: It's often difficult/impossible to get any kind of documentation for these kinds of cheap hardware items on AliExpress, and without developer docs or schematics you may be sunk.  You likely must write your own firmware in C using the Nordic SDK.  You'll need a [JTAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTAG) to load firmware onto the board, but it's unclear what pins on the board allow this.  It's also unclear what hardware settings you should use with the Nordic SDK -- clock config, etc.  If you can't get documentation you should run away and save yourself the trouble.

Comment: @davidgyoung I was able to find the manufacture name and schematics after some digging. (Updated post). One other seller of the module claims ```Configuration tool
The configuration tool which you can download LightBlue ,a  mobile app design for developer check and configure yunjia iBeacon```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's iBeacon framework is dirt-simple and very easy to use. It allows you to listen for beacons based a unique UUID, major id, and minor ID. It lets you know when a beacon enters or leaves range, and provides crude (immediate, near, medium, and far) distance values. You can create "beacon regions" that will notify your app when you enter or leave them. That's about it.

If you want to do something like read barometric pressure or temperature readings, you will need to either write your own low-level BLE code or use an existing library. My guess is that these modules are using very standard hardware and that you should be able to find libraries to read their specialized data.

Failing that, you will need specifications on their BLE interface and need to learn how to write Apple Core Bluetooth code. (The link you posted has zero specifications for the units. The only thing it provides is the numbers "nRF51822 bluetooth module ibeacon LPS22HB" (It's not in well-formed English so I don't know how to parse those descriptive terms. I'd google those numbers) Note that Core Bluetooth is a fairly low-level framework and not very easy to learn.

### EDIT:

Googling "nRF51822", that is apparently an ARM based chip that includes radio hardware that supports BLE. It sounds like that is a general-purpose chip that vendor would use to build a BLE module. Given that, you'd probably have to reverse-engineer it to figure out how it works.

The "LPS22HB" appears to be a solid state pressure sensor that can be used to build a barometric pressure measurement device. It's no doubt interfaced with the "nRF51822". Without specs you're going to have a very hard time figuring out *how* it's interfaced however.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, I've been doing more research and I found through their website the specs and SDK's you can use [link]<http://www.holyiot.com/tp/2019042815352698708.pdf>. Right now I am learning about the UID's and values it transmits to start. I think there is a massive opportunity with these devices! I will keep researching and try to connect it a computer.

Comment: Good job finding that document. The most useful link in that doc appears to be the one to the development tools: https://www.nordicsemi.com/DocLib/Content/User_Guides/getting_started/latest/UG/common/n ordic_tools. Unfortunately, that returns a page not found error. You might need to go to the top page of Nordic Semiconductor and try to find an updated link.